# R Regex expression with gsub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am using gsub regex to select last part of expression

Example:

- "Bla-text-01" - I want -> "text-01"
- "Name-xpto-08" - I want -> "xpto-08"
- "text-text-04" - I want -> "text-04"
- "new-blaxpto-morexpto-07" -  I want -> "morexpto-07"
- "new-new-new-bla-ready-05" - I want -> "ready-05"

I created this code that works with first 3 cases but now I have a new request to also work with 5 cases.

```
gsub(x = match$id,
          pattern =  "(.*?-)(.*)",
          replacement = "\\2")
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Just match the regular expression `[a-z]+-\\d+$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/81sd4U/1). You may need to change `[a-z]` to `[a-zA-Z]` or set the case-indifferent flag. Hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
sub(".*-(.*-.*)$", "\\1", x)
## [1] "text-01"     "xpto-08"     "text-04"     "morexpto-07" "ready-05"
```

Other approaches would be:

```
# 2. use basename/dirname
xx <- gsub("-", "/", x)
paste(basename(dirname(xx)), basename(xx), sep = "-")
## [1] "text-01"     "xpto-08"     "text-04"     "morexpto-07" "ready-05"   

# 3. use scan
f <- function(x) {
  scan(text = x, what = "", sep = "-", quiet = TRUE) |>  
    tail(2) |>
    paste(collapse = "-")
}
sapply(x, f)
##              Bla-text-01             Name-xpto-08             text-text-04 
##                "text-01"                "xpto-08"                "text-04" 
##  new-blaxpto-morexpto-07 new-new-new-bla-ready-05 
##            "morexpto-07"               "ready-05"
```

### Note

Input in reproducible form:

```
x <- c("Bla-text-01", "Name-xpto-08", "text-text-04", "new-blaxpto-morexpto-07", 
"new-new-new-bla-ready-05")
```

Comment: Might as well add `vapply(strsplit(x, "-"), function(x) paste(tail(x, 2L), collapse = "-"), "")`...

Comment: 2nd way is cleaver, but `.*-(.*-.*)$` may cause a many backtracking steps with a long string. It's safer to write it in a more explicit way: `(?:[^-]*-)*([^-]*-[^-]*])$`. Or better in pcre flavor: `^(?>[^-]*-)*([^-]*-[^-]*])$`

Answer (score 2):

```r
x <- c("Bla-text-01",
       "Name-xpto-08", 
       "text-text-04", 
       "new-blaxpto-morexpto-07", 
       "new-new-new-bla-ready-05")

sub("^.*-([^-]*-[^-]*)$", "\\1", x)
## [1] "text-01"     "xpto-08"     "text-04"     "morexpto-07" "ready-05"
```